# How to set up a Hybrid SLI compatible motherboard to Hybrid SLI mode?

Tags: windows-xp

I recently bought an ASUS M3N78-EM motherboard (it is a Hybrid SLI compatible mainboard with GeForce 8300 onboard) and a XFX GeForce 9400GT (1GB) card. Now, I need to enable Hybrid SLI mode so that I can take advantage of that technology. However, I have been told by some people that Windows XP doesn't have support for Hybrid SLI.

So, is it possible to make use of Hybrid SLI mode under Windows XP?

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [this](http://www.nvidia.com/content/includes/images/us/product_detail/pdf/hybrid_sli_0308.pdf) manual which on page 6 says:

> Hybrid SLI is only supported on the Windows Vista® operating system.

Answer (score 1):

All sign's point toward no, this is not possible in Windows XP.  Fortunately for you, Windows 7 is just around the corner.  I would install Vista (which isn't really too bad), and wait a few short months for an upgrade to 7.

I feel that you would benefit more though, if you wanted to stay in XP, by running a single card and forgetting about SLI all together.  You can get something with very respectable performance, such as a GTX260 for under $200.